# Is there any ADA parser written in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, ada

I am looking to parse ADA code and construct its AST using Java. My belief was that there's a parser written in Java to parse almost every programming language, however after days of research I haven't found anything.

The only promising tool I've found is libadalang (https://github.com/AdaCore/libadalang) by Adacore. However, this only provides api for Ada and Python (although in the readme file Java is mentioned).

Do you have anything to suggest? If there's no direct way of parsing Ada using Java, is any of you familiar with any library that could work as an intermediate? For example, parse Ada using XXX tool and store the AST in a schema (e.g. XML) and then parse the XML using Java?

Comment: Beside parsers there are grammars (a combination in https://github.com/slebok/zoo/blob/master/zoo/ada/ada2005/txl/lehyaric-cordy/fetched/ada.grm). Using an **ANTLR** grammar in java would be feasible. Converting one grammar into an other would be straightforward.

Comment: IIRC there's an ANTLR Ada grammar.

Comment: The scarcity of ressources to parse Ada makes the decision to put this question on hold as off-topic questionable at best. All current answers are helpful for people wanting to access an Ada AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the Libadalang developers, we have indeed planned adding Java bindings at some point, but this is not a high priority item for the moment.

Having a serializer for a common format is something that would be quite easy to add though, especially to the python API were you have full introspection on the tree.

Here is a JSON serializer for the python API of Libadalang:

```
import json

def node_to_data(self):
    if isinstance(self, ASTList):
        return [i.to_data() for i in self if i is not None]
    else:
        return {n: v.to_data()
                for n, v in self.iter_fields(with_properties=False)
                if v is not None}

def token_to_data(self):
    return {"kind": "Token", "token_kind": self.kind, "text": self.text}

ASTNode.to_data = node_to_data
Token.to_data = token_to_data
ASTNode.to_json = lambda self: json.dumps(self.to_data())
```

I'll add this to the development version of Libadalang soon!

Comment: I agree with the feasibility of exploiting the current implementation to generate an intermediate format that could be parsable byJava (e.g. XML or JSON you suggest). In fact, Adacore offers this functionality of generating the AST in form of an XML file using Ada (as opposed to Python based on your suggestion). Your suggestion is quite solid however, at this point we are only able to execute Java commands from our platform, thus including an intermediate level other than Java is not an option. Unless we use the Ada-Java interface or a Python-Java interface (if any).

Comment: Although this answer does not reply my original question I will mark it as correct because the only alternative I have found is very close to what you suggested. The alternative I am talking about comes directly from adacore. There's a tool called gnat2xml that returns an xml file of the ada's file AST. You can then use any xml library to parse this XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've read that it is possible to call native C libraries from Java.

You could make a C binding to [ASIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Semantic_Interface_Specification) (Ada Semantic Interface Specification), and then call that from Java.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is already an AJIS (Ada-Java Interface Specification) component available as far as I know. This is going to be my ultimate choice if I don't find anything more straight forward.